How can I use a private-framework's function in Xcode?
I am trying to understand how to use private frameworks in Xcode. Specifically I want to call the MTDeviceCreateList() from the MultitouchSupport-Framework to create a minimal working example. I created this Github-Repo to share what I have tried.
The workingButUglyMain.m uses dynamic linking and successfully calls the function, but I saw many people write custom headers to make a private-framework's functions accessible without that complicated linking. I fail to understand and replicate it though. I tried creating such a header with MultitouchSupport.h and linking the framework by adding it to the frameworks and setting the Other Linker Flags in build-settings. I also tried dynamic loading using NSBundle's bundleWithPath(). I always get Undefined symbol: _MTDeviceCreateList error. The framework should be stored in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.
Here are some of the sources I used:

https://www.jviotti.com/2023/11/20/exploring-macos-private-frameworks.html#approach-3-hopper-disassembler
https://github.com/NilStack/HelloPF/tree/master
https://medium.com/swiftworld/swift-world-how-to-use-private-framework-in-swift-b369209e25be


Post a [mre] in the question please. How/where did you add the MultitouchSupport framework? When do you get the Undefined symbol: _MTDeviceCreateList error?

I solved it. My first mistake was to not properly add the framework-dependency. You need to add the whole folder so in my case: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework. The second problem was that it does not work if the project is in SANDBOX-mode. Might be use-case-specific though.
